# How to get PropertyInfo of the property inside child declared in parent using MemberExpression?

Tags: c#, .net

`Parent` class has only property `Name`, `Child` class inherits `Parent` with no its own props.
PropertyInfo's for `Parent.Name` and `Child.Name` are different objects (very similar but still different).
There is a well-known way to obtain PropertyInfo having member expression, but it always returns PropertyInfo for *parent* object, not for *child* (see the code below).
Is there a way to get PropertyInfo object for `Child.Name` having `c => c.Name` on input and using MemberExpressions?

UPDATE: `MemberInfo.HasSameMetadataDefinitionAs` returns true for Parent's and Child's Name property, but still wondering if I can make `MemberExpression` return Child's PropertyInfo.

```
void Main()
{
    // instantiate Parent and Child
    var parent = new Parent();
    var child = new Child();

    // Get PropertyInfo's for the Name property of the parent and of the child
    var parentNamePropertyInfo = (parent.GetType().GetProperty("Name"));
    var childNamePropertyInfo = (child.GetType().GetProperty("Name"));

    // see they are different
    Debug.WriteLine($"same property info's? { parentNamePropertyInfo == childNamePropertyInfo}");

    // Trying to get PropertyInfo of Child.Name but still having the one of the Parent.Name:
    Expression<Func<Child, string>> expr = (p => p.Name);
    MemberExpression member = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
    PropertyInfo pi = (PropertyInfo)member.Member;
    
    Debug.WriteLine(
        pi == parentNamePropertyInfo ? "parent's info" :
        pi == childNamePropertyInfo ? "childs's info" :
        "None");
    
}

public class Parent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
}
```